# Como puedo mostras los registros de mi BD de Firebase en un Recycler View?

Tags: android-studio, firebase

El siguien codigo es el fragment de los usuarios

1. public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {

   ```
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private UserAdapter userAdapter;
        private List<User> mUsers;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_users,container,false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        readUser();
        return view;
    }

        private void readUser() {
            final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mUsers.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        assert firebaseUser != null;
                        assert user != null;
                        if(!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }
                    }
                    userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(),mUsers);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

















    Y este codigo es el adaptador del recible. cuando depuro el programa    en la variables me muestra los registro pero no me los
   ```

   muestra en la    pantalla del recycler
   public class UserAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>{    private Context
   mContext;    private List mUsers;
   public UserAdapter (Context mContext, List mUsers){
   this.mContext = mContext;
   this.mUsers = mUsers;    }
   @NonNull    @Override    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item,parent,false);
   return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);    }
   @Override    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   ```
    User user = mUsers.get(position);
    holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
    if(user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
        holder.profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }else{
        Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.profile_image);
    }    }
    @Override    public int getItemCount() {
    return mUsers.size();    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView username;
    public ImageView profile_image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    }    }
   ```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema, dónde? ¿Muestra error? ¿Qué error?

Comment: Nuevamente te invitamos a revisar [ask], comenta que problema tienes, que se muestra en el LogCat

Comment: No muestra ningun error de sintaxis pero tampoco me mustra los registros

Comment: probaste debugeando a ver si te esta trayendo los datos ? probaste poniendo userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() abajo de setAdapter ?